# How to add class dynamically to a div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add a class dynamically for that i use addClass method then  class is adding but it doesn't go my requirement.Here is my code

```
 <div id="form-copy">
   <div class="abc">
       Here some code is there....
   <div>
 <div>
```

I am trying like this..

```
  var p = 0;
  for(var i =0; i<n;i++){
    $(".abc:first").clone(true).appendTo("#form-copy")
    $(".abc").addClass( "dynamicClass"+ ++p);
  }
now am getting output is...
 if here n=3
     <div class="abc dynamicClass1 dynamicClass2 dynamicClass3">...</div>
     <div class="abc dynamicClass1 dynamicClass2 dynamicClass3">...</div>
     <div class="abc dynamicClass1 dynamicClass2 dynamicClass3">...</div>

But i need output like this
  if here n=3
     <div class="abc dynamicClass1">...</div>
     <div class="abc dynamicClass2">...</div>
     <div class="abc dynamicClass3">...</div>

Plese help me to get like this output.Thank you
```

Comment: `$(".abc")` get all divs with `abc` class, not only the one you just created(cloned). Check Bilal's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i =0; i<n;i++){
    $(".abc:first").clone().appendTo("#form-copy").addClass("dynamicClass" + (i + 1));
  }
```

Comment: Clear, handy and nice chaining!

Comment: Thanks to all. Here to gain and deliver some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Try this:

```
<div id="form-copy">
  <div class="abc" id="abc">
    Here some code is there....
 </div>
</div>


var p = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < n;i++ ){
    $(".abc:first").clone(true).appendTo("#form-copy")
    $("#abc").removeClass().addClass( "abc dynamicClass"+ ++p);
}
```

Comment: Did you test your solution ? Caus this is not working ^^

Comment: I edit it, and this will do the trick... Thanks for mentioning that.